# Flutter bloc: state does not change after changing new event

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, equatable, onreadystatechange, flutter-exception

I want to navigate to the next screen after bloc listener checks the state, but in my UI, the bloc listener does not know that the state has changed. Therefore, the state is changed on<event>((state,emit)) after emitting to the next state.

Here is my code:

1. Bloc

   ```dart
   import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
   import 'package:bloctest/bloc/events.dart';
   import 'package:bloctest/bloc/states.dart';

   class AppBloc extends Bloc<AppEvent,AppState>{

     AppBloc(AppState initialState):super(initialState){

       on<AppStartEvent>((event, emit) {
         emit(AppInitState());
       });

       on<NavigatorButtonPressed>((event, emit) {
         emit(NavigationSucceedState());
         print('navigation succeed');
       });
     }
   }
   ```
2. Bloc Listener screen

   ```dart
   import 'package:bloctest/bloc/bloc.dart';
   import 'package:bloctest/bloc/states.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

   import 'bloc/events.dart';
   import 'main2.dart';
   void main() {
     runApp(const MyApp());
   }

   class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
     const MyApp({super.key});

     @override
     State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
   }

   class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
     bool isNavigationSuccess=false;
     AppBloc appBloc=AppBloc(AppInitState());
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
         home: BlocProvider<AppBloc>(
             create: (context)=>AppBloc(AppInitState())..add(AppStartEvent()),
             child: Scaffold(
               body: BlocListener<AppBloc, AppState>(
                 listener: (context , state)async{

                   if(state is NavigationSucceedState){
                  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
                     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MyApp2()));
                   }
                 },
                 child:BlocBuilder<AppBloc,AppState>(
                 builder:(context,state){
                 context.read<AppBloc>().add(AppStartEvent());
                 return state is AppStartingState?const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),):
                 Scaffold(
                       body: SafeArea(child: Center(
                         child: ElevatedButton(
                             onPressed: () {
                              appBloc.add(NavigatorButtonPressed());
                             },
                             child: const Text('tap to go to next page')),
                       )),
                     );
                  }
               ),
             ),

         ),
       )
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: show your state classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class AppBloc extends Bloc<AppEvent,AppState>{

  AppBloc() : super(AppStartingState()){

    on<NavigatorButtonPressed>((event, emit) {
      emit(NavigationSucceedState());
      print('navigation succeed');
    });
  }
}
```

In UI:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isNavigationSuccess = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocProvider<AppBloc>(
        create: (context) => AppBloc(),
        child: BlocListener<AppBloc, AppState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is NavigationSucceedState) {
              Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp2()));
              });
            }
          },
          child: BlocBuilder<AppBloc, AppState>(
            builder: (context, state) => state is AppStartingState
                ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : Scaffold(
                    body: SafeArea(
                      child: Center(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              context.read<AppBloc>.add(
                                NavigatorButtonPressed(),
                              );
                            },
                            child: const Text('tap to go to next page')),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, i just added this line extra that worked. create: (context)=>AppBloc()..add(AppStartEvent()), and ()=> this kind of return type doesnot work at my project, just simple return works

Answer (score 0):

Reason of the problem is the instance of the bloc, if you take a look you have created on instance in you state (AppBloc appBloc=AppBloc(AppInitState());) and other one in provide constructor (create: (context)=>AppBloc(AppInitState())..add(AppStartEvent()),) so if you can see in listener you are listening states change from second bloc instance but you are adding event to your first instance , and as they are different objects state changing from one is not available in second, so you  on you on tap method you can add event to your provided bloc by context.read().add and it will work.

Comment: I think there will no diffrence between instance 1 and 2 because They are only agents of class, not state!,